# Perform a HTTP request of Audio URL from the playlist in JustAudio

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player, just-audio

The HLS stream audio files are accessible via url like media/....stream/hls. This further require a GET HTTP request to be performed to fetch the actual M3U8 audio file which can be played through the player.

How this additional http request be performed while preparing the playlist object in Just Audio music player?

I'm able to make the player work using the following logic, where I fetch M3U8 audio file for all the hls stream url and prepare a playlist.

```
Future<void> _init() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.audioURLs!.length; i++) {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.audioURLs![i]),
          headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});
      final audioUrl = json.decode(response.body);
      listOfAudioSources.add(
        AudioSource.uri(
          Uri.parse(audioUrl['url']),
          tag: MediaItem(
            id: '${_nextMediaId++}',
            album: widget.audioTitles![i],
            title: widget.artistName!,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: listOfAudioSources);
await _player.setAudioSource(playlist);
```

Above logic causes player to load after a while. So wondering how can I improve the logic such that when user tries to play the music item from the playlist at that time only, HTTP Request is executed and M3U8 Audio files are fetched. More like lazy, on request fetch.

Comment: "More like lazy, on request fetch." - don't use `for` loop then, fetch data for the item you want to play, not all of them

Comment: @pskink That's right! However, playlist here needs to be precomputed m3u8 audio urls lists because when I use player.play, it just plays that specific item. 
I'm not able to figure out on how would I make a HTTP request for that specific item and then pass it to player.play. 

There could be a different way to approach it, which I am not aware of !

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is not so much about M3U8, it is more about adding a large number of children to a `ConcatenatingAudioSource`. If that is the case, please see this issue: https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/294

Comment: @RyanHeise Thanks for responding to this and working passionately on the library. Appreciate that ! Tried feature/treadmill but didn't help. 

The function _init() remained same as before and I set useLazyPreparation to True.

final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children: listOfAudioSources, useLazyPreparation: true);

Player still performs HTTP request to all given URLs (40 of them) which takes around 10-12 seconds and player isn't active until then.

I'm trying this in iPhone14 IOS Simulator.

Comment: @RyanHeise LazyPreparation should work in general. Like Normal URL stays in the list but renders only next 2 items from the list as you implemented in AudioPlayer.m. 
Should that listOfAudioSources be generated differently ? 

I'm not a pro in Dart language. So might be doing something wrong at basic level.

Comment: The treadmill branch doesn't actually respect `useLazyPreparation`, it just enables it all the time regardless of that option. I haven't heard of any bugs with it yet, so if you have found a bug with it, please report it so that it can be reproduced and investigated.